# Getting Error while rendering element in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
<div className="col-xs-12">
                        {
                            _.each(questiondata, ((category, idx) => {
                                _.map(category.GroupedCategory, function (subCategory, idxs) {
                                    _.each(subCategory, function (qsc, i) {
                                        return <Question key={i + 'q'} data={qsc.toString()} qId={i + 'q'} events={props.events.eMenuOptionselect} />
                                    })
                                })
                            }))

                        }
                        <div className="btn btn-primary pull-right" onClick={props.events.eMenuOnsave}>Save</div>
                    </div>
```

I am getting this error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
>   with keys {ClientProductId, ProviderProductId, ProductTypeCode,
>   ProviderId, Fields, Errors, GroupedCategory}). If you meant to render
>   a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object
>   using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render
>   method of `RequireProvider`.

Can Anyone Help ?

Comment: Can you paste a sample of `questiondata` so that we can help you?

Comment: Your posted code does not have any errors. You have to look at all places where you use `questiondata` to find the error under the `RequireProvider` component

Comment: Issue is resolved now . i have to return _.map inside _.each and it works fine